# Mock Multiple Resttemplates

Tags: mocking, mockito, junit4, junit5, spring-test

I'm trying to mock following two rest templates

```
    ResponseEntity<UserDetailsResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri.toString(),
                        HttpMethod.POST, entity, UserDetailsResponse.class);
    
    ResponseEntity<AccountDetailsResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri.toString(),
                        HttpMethod.POST, entity, AccountDetailsResponse.class);


Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class),
             Mockito.<org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?>>any(), Mockito.<Class<UserDetailsResponse>>any()))
            .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(UserMockData.UserDetailsResponse(), HttpStatus.OK));

Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class),
             Mockito.<org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<?>>any(), Mockito.<Class<AccountDetailsResponse>>any()))
            .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(AccountMockData.AccountDetailsResponse(), HttpStatus.OK));
```

When I try with approach, by default it's taking the second mocked one and getting class cast exception with response like Account details cannot cast to UserDetails

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
Mockito.<Class<UserDetailsResponse>>any()
Mockito.<Class<AccountDetailsResponse>>any()
```

Try using

```
Mockito.any(UserDetailsResponse.class)
Mockito.any(AccountDetailsResponse.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically in case to mock multiplerest template calls, you can specify the specific URI that will be invoked, instead of using `Mockito.any(String.class)`.

Something like this will work.

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate
  .exchange(Mockito.eq("uri1"), Mockito.eq(HttpMethod.POST), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(Foo.class))).thenReturn("response-1");
```

And then

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate
  .exchange(Mockito.eq("uri2"), Mockito.eq(HttpMethod.POST), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(Foo.class))).thenReturn("response-2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    UserDetailsResponse  userDetailsResponse = new UserDetailsResponse();
    //Can set the userDetailsResponse values here
    
    AccountDetailsResponse accountDetailsResponse = new AccountDetailsResponse();
    //Can set the accountDetailsResponse values here

    Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.any(String.class)
            , Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class)
            , Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class)
            , Mockito.eq(UserDetailsResponse.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(userDetailsResponse, HttpStatus.OK));


    Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.any(String.class)
            , Mockito.eq(HttpMethod.POST)
            , Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class)
            , Mockito.eq(AccountDetailsResponse.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(accountDetailsResponse, HttpStatus.OK));
```

Comment: `Mockito.eq(AccountDetailsResponse.class)` doesn't make sense, please check

Comment: In both mock statements only Response class type indicates relevant class . This will differentiate the rest calls and give the proper response. Let me know if you have different opinion. I have tested this , it will work. @HariHaravelan